# PHP: IF() Equal TO Not working

Tags: php, session, if-statement

```
if($_SESSION['auth'] != 2 || $_SESSION['auth'] != 3){
    header("location:../login/login.php");
}
```

what am i doing wrong, it keeps sending me back,

its only when session is 1 or not set, it should run the `header()`

Comment: I think you are confusing && with ||, btw, you also might want to check if the session `isset`

Comment: i tried whit &&, and now it works, thank you, and i switched the two whit each other :)

Comment: for you application you can use `var_dump($_SESSION,($_SESSION['auth'] != 2 || $_SESSION['auth'] != 3 ))` before if and `die()` after var_dump

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
if( (!isset($_SESSION['auth']) || ($_SESSION['auth'] == 1)){
    header("location:../login/login.php");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

"its only when session is 1 or not set, it should run the header()"

So you need to check if session equals to 1 or if session is empty. Try the following code.

```
if($_SESSION['auth'] == 1 || empty($_SESSION['auth'])){
    header("location:../login/login.php");
}
```

And make sure you've started the session on this page.